# How to check if a partition for an HDFS dataset/table exists using Dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, hdfs

I have an HDFS dataset `person_details` which is partitioned by date. Say this is a sample partition: `hdfs://<path>/person_details/date=20210906`.
I am using a python script to work with this dataset. How can I check if a particular partition (not the whole dataset) exists using Dataframes?

Comment: will SHOW PARTITIONS suffice requiement

Comment: No, I need to handle the result of whether or not the partition exists in the code using a subsequent if condition. This is not for console.

Comment: we can may be add condition to filter data  based on partition values

Comment: the idea is to delete the existing partition in case of a rerun. Say the job executed and created a partition for date 20210906. If I need to rerun the job on the same date (ad hoc runs are a project requirement), it will just append the data output by the 2nd run into the partition created by the first run. I don't want that. So in case of a rerun, I want to delete the existing partition and create a fresh one for the same date. For that, I want to check if the partition exists already. If yes, delete it, else continue.

Comment: one way of achieving this is writing data frame with overwrite mode instead of append mode..other way may be use python lib to iterate over the folder and remove required partitions

Comment: my project uses PySpark for interfacing with hdfs and it's sort of preset at append, not overwrite. For the iteration method, this process could get lengthy as the number of partitions increase daily.

Answer (score 1):

I will fix AdibP's answer, because date is system word and must be quoted by ` as hive like. Value needs to quote too, by ' in this case.

```
spark.sql("show partitions person_details partition(`date`='20210906')").count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments, maybe you could use `show partitions` and then count the resulted dataframe to determine whether a specific partition exists or not.

```
spark.sql("show partitions person_details partition(date=20210906)").count()
```

it will give you 0 if a partition doesn't exist.

Comment: gave it a  quick try on CLI... it's throwing syntax error